# jQuery .each loop not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, submit

I have a web app that use jquery to submit all forms in the page. The code is like this :

```
        $('form').each(function()
        {
            $(this).submit();
        });
```

This is working great in IE and FireFox but on Chrome and Safari it is only submitting the first form of the page, ignoring totally the rest.

The app is a asp.net mvc and the forms are posted to a HttpPost action in my controller.

If anyone has any idea or see something I did totally wrong please advise, it will be appreciated.

Thx and have a nice day.

Comment: UM, are they submitting to the same page? If so, how in the world is IE and Firefox working? Are they submitting to new windows, ajax calls, iframes?

Comment: And if anything is working in any browser, you do not need `.each()` at all. Just do `$('form').submit()` and all forms should be submitted!

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form typically does a HTTP POST request that uploads the form data to the URL specified in the form's `action` attribute (elements like `input` and `textarea`).

You didn't show enough code to say for sure, but it sounds like your problem is that when the first form is submitted the javascript loop ends and will not submit subsequent forms.

You either need to do something like use AJAX, or use an `IFRAME` for each form, or group all your fields in the same, single `FORM`.

You will receive better help if you post the full markup (HTML) that shows these multiple forms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The forms are created with javascript and the number of forms to be post depends on the user (user can add as many form as they need). The form's submit button are hidden and I have one ''submit all'' button that call the .each loop I posted.
My app is in ASP.NET MVC so my forms are posted to a httppost action in the controller. Like I said it is only a problem with Chrome, I am gonna try a different loop in javascript instead of jquery.